# check if string array contains value

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

I have to check, if String Array `test2[]` contains a value of `test1[]`. How to do that? Both Arrays have different size. I also have to check if `test2[]` contains a substring of `test1[]`.

```
String[] test = {"Test1", "Test2"};
String[] test2 = {"Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test1 - Test7"};
```

Comment: 2 foreach loops will do thee trick

Comment: "Contains" is a way too general here. Please clarify - should `test2` contain `test` as a subset, or it should contain any value from `test` or it should contain a (continuous or not) subsequence of `test`

Comment: HashSet + contains would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You just need couple nested loops and iterate. Your question is ambiguous and the `contains` word you say might mean `equals` or `contains the substring`. In either case, if you want equal match, just replace `.contains()` with `.equals()`.

```
for (String value : test) {
        for (String sampleString : test2) {
            if (sampleString.contains(value)) {
                System.out.println("Value " + value + " is contained in the array in " + sampleString);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkIfHaveSameElements(String[] test1, String[] test2) {
    for (String str2 : test2) {
        for (String str1 : test1) {
            if (str2.equals(str1)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just pass your arrays as method call argumnents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two for loops, one to iterate `test` and the other to check if the item is contained in `test2`

```
public static boolean checkIfExists(String[] arr, String item) {
    for (String n : arr) {

         if (n.contains(item)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
```

And in main method

```
String[] test = {"Test1", "Test2"};
String[] test2 = {"Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test1 - Test7"};
for(String t : test) {
    System.out.println(checkIfExists(test2, t));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 APIs, I am first checking whether the entire string is present or whether the substring is present.

```
public class CheckString {

public static void main(String[] args) {      

    String[] test = {"Test1", "Test3", "Test2"};
    String[] test2 = {"Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test1 - Test7"};

    boolean isPresent = Arrays.stream(test2)
                              .filter(str->{
                               return Arrays.asList(test).indexOf(str) > 0 || checkString(test,str);
                               })
                              .collect(Collectors.toList())
                              .isEmpty();

    System.out.println(!isPresent);

    }
    private static boolean checkString(String[] strs, String chkStr){
        for(String str: strs){
            if(chkStr.contains(str)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```